# JAXB how to map either text or unknown tag (countable set)

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm struggling with mapping node which can be either plain text or node which is unknown, but within set that I know all possibilities. For instance:

```
<some-root>
    ...
    <data type="text/plain">10000</data>
    ...
<some-root>
```

or

```
<some-root>
    ...
    <data type="...">
        <date type="DateTime">2015-10-05T22:45:00.000Z</date>
    </data>
    ...
<some-root>
```

As I said I know all possible tags which can be nested with `<data>`. That's why it would be good to somehow map them using `lax=true` as well (if possible)

Please do not post answer about changing structure cause this is external service. I do not have way to change it. There are already too many services which rely on that layout (but they are written by other programmers in other languages)